# Where to start learning to understand SQL Server architecture and internals?

Tags: sql-server

I have a basic knowledge of T-SQL and SQL Server components. My goal is to master my skills and learn **everything** about SQL Server to eventually become DBA in the future. I would like to understand deep SQL Server internals, how exactly everything works, when and why. Could you please suggest me a good place to start? IMHO it's just not possible by doing the programming work.

Comment: Books: "SQL Server 2008 Internals" (Microsoft Press) and "Professional SQL Server 2008 Internals and Troubleshooting" (Wrox) would be a good start but there are still large parts of the product not covered by either of these.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just to add to the suggestions on this thread, you might find these interesting

Books:

- I found Thomas Larock's [DBA Survior](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430227877) very useful. It doesn't go deep into SQL Server internals, but it has right pointers to guide a newbie towards becoming a successful DBA. If you are past that newbie stage, you can skip this.
- Rod Colledge's [SQL Server 2008 Administration in action](https://www.manning.com/books/sql-server-2008-administration-in-action) was useful for me as a next step from DBA Survior
- [Troubleshooting SQL Server](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/troubleshooting-sql-server-a-guide-for-the-accidental-dba) by Jonathan Kehayias is a great book. It is available as a free download. Also take a look at other books available on [SSC](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/books). I am currently reading a [book](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/sql-server-execution-plans) on execution plans by Grant Fritchey.

There are some awesome blogs out there:

- Read everything under the category ["involuntary DBA"](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/category/involuntary-dba/) on Paul Randal's blog. While I understand that you obviously are not an involuntary DBA, they tend to be simpler while explaining things to newbies.
- Buckwoody has a great blog [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/buckwoody/) and also a useful SQL Server reference guide [here](https://www.informit.com/authors/bio/6040e7f4-9b52-4f0f-b12e-1d25909d1d34). He is blogging about Windows Azure stuff thesedays but you can check the archives

Other Blogs in random order

- [Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/)
- [Grant Fritchey](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/author/grant-fritchey/)
- [Brent Ozar](https://www.brentozar.com/)
- [Thomas LaRock](https://thomaslarock.com/)
- [Pinal Dave](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/)
- [Phil Factor](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/author/phil-factor/)

Podcasts:

- There are a few SQL Server related podcasts on [DotNetRocks](https://www.dotnetrocks.com/)
- Also here on [SQL Down Under](https://web.archive.org/web/20130312201905/http://www.sqldownunder.com:80/Resources/Podcast.aspx)

Other great sites - SSC, MSSQL Tips, SQLCAT, LessThanDot.

This list is in no way complete and if I have missed some important books/sites/blogs, thats because I too am still learning and my knowledge is limited. Lets hope the others on this thread add more resources.

Good luck!

**UPDATE**: I forgot to include [SQL Server Performance Survival Guide](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5957.sql-server-performance-survival-guide.aspx) technet article which has loads of links and pointers.

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of very good resources out there. [Microsoft certifications](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/certification/cert-sql-server.aspx) are a good place to start, especially if you have no formal training or experience.

To add to the above links,

- [SQL Skills w/ Paul Randal, Kimberly Tripp](http://www.sqlskills.com/)
- [Glenn Berry](http://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/)
- [Denny Cherry](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/sql-server/)
- [SQL ServerPedia (Now Toad World)](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/default.aspx)
- [Brad McGehee](http://www.bradmcgehee.com/)
- [Adam Machanic](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/)

Topics covered in these blogs may be a bit advanced if you are just starting out.
There is a lot of information to know for SQL Server, try not to get ahead of yourself. These days, there are a lot of SQL deployments involving SANs, so you will want to eventually look at [storage sites](http://sqlserverio.com/) as well. IMO, try to follow the Microsoft certification because it is a structured process that will provide a very good foundation to build from(no i don't work for microsoft). It may also help you get your foot in the door somewhere to start using what you learn.

It's an interesting journey..Good luck!

edit: corrected the spelling of Adam's last name

Answer (score 4):

Definately SQL Server 2008 Internals (MSPress) by Kalen Delaney is a good book on the internal workings of the product itself.  For a reference book, I'd also check out Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Bible (Wiley) by Paul Nielsen.  This is a great desk reference book for the professional DBA.  Unfortunately there is no "one-stop-shop" when it comes to a particular book on SQL Server, but these are good to start your journey.

Good luck!